# MATLAB table averages

Tags: matlab

My MATALB talbe looks like:

table_variables =

```
Meas   Group1    Group2    Subject_id    Age      Sex       Var1   Var2
___    _____     _____     __________    ___    ________    ____   ____

 1     'A'       '0'       1             60     'Male'      48     150
 2     'A'       '0'       1             60     'Male'      47     100
 3     'A'       '0'       1             60     'Male'      48     90
 4     'A'       '0'       1             60     'Male'      38     250
 1     'A'       '3'       2             50     'Male'      50     450
 2     'A'       '3'       2             50     'Male'      43     150      
 3     'A'       '3'       2             50     'Male'      45     100      
 ...
 ...

 1     'B'       '2'       900           66     'Female'    66     170      
 2     'B'       '2'       900           66     'Female'    68     110
 3     'B'       '2'       900           66     'Female'    70     250
```

For each subject there are multiple measurements for the variables Var1 and Var2. How can I create a new table with the averages for each subject? Please suppose that I have more than 2 variables so the code:

```
mean_var1 =    varfun(@mean,T,'InputVariables','Var1',...
        'GroupingVariables','Subject_id')
mean_var2 =    varfun(@mean,T,'InputVariables','Var2',...
        'GroupingVariables','Subject_id')
```

Comment: Simply use the `mean` function on a table column, e.g. `mean( tablename.Var1 )`.

Comment: Hi Mattihias, I apologize...I was just updating my question...is there a way to do it for all the variables at once (defining the grouping variable)

Comment: What didn't work with the provided code?

Comment: it worked, but if I have 100 Variables to take the mean I dont want to do it for each variable...I was wondering if there was another way..

Comment: @gabboshow - do you have the [Database Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/database/index.html) available to you? It might be very easy to do this with SQL. (...or even possibly with some creative Excel).

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation for [`varfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varfun.html), the [`'InputVariables'`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varfun.html#input_argument_namevalue_inputvariables) property can be passed the following:

> Variables of `A` to pass to `func`, specified as the comma-separated pair
>   consisting of `'InputVariables'` and a positive integer, vector of
>   positive integers, variable name, cell array of variable names, or
>   logical vector, or an anonymous function that returns a logical
>   scalar.

So you have a few options. One example, using the logical vector mask:

```
ID = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2];
var_1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var_2 = fliplr(var_1);

t = table(ID.', var_1.', var_2.', 'VariableNames', {'ID', 'var_1', 'var_2'});

varmask = [false true true];
varmeans = varfun(@mean, t, 'InputVariables', varmask, 'GroupingVariables', 'ID');
```

Which returns the following table:

```
varmeans = 

         ID    GroupCount    mean_var_1    mean_var_2
         __    __________    __________    __________

    1    1     3             2             5         
    2    2     3             5             2
```

This approach assumes that the variables are always at the end of the table. For a more robust approach you would probably want to generate a cell array of the variable names to process.

Using the above example:

```
nvars = 2;
varnames = sprintfc('var_%u', 1:nvars); %  Caveat, sprintfc is an undocumented function
varmeans = varfun(@mean, t, 'InputVariables', varnames, 'GroupingVariables', 'ID');
```

Will return the same results. I have used `sprintfc` here to avoid intermediate steps, but do note that it is an undocumented function so the usual caveats apply.